# Crashing Math App

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am making a simple math addition app and Xcode says it builds correctly, but the app won't open up on the simulator or on my device. It is a winow based application, but I'm manually adding a `UITabBarController`.

This is what my AreaViewController.h says

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AreaViewController : UIViewController {
  <snipped ivars>
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add11;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add12;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add13;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add21;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add22;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add23;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add31;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add32;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *add33;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *add1Result;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *add2Result;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *add3Result;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;

@end
```

My AreaViewController.m

```
#import "AreaViewController.h"


@implementation AreaViewController

@synthesize add11, add12, add13;
@synthesize add21, add22, add23;
@synthesize add31, add32, add33;
@synthesize add1Result, add2Result, add3Result;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
 float floatAdd1Result=[add11.text floatValue]+[add12.text floatValue]+[add13.text floatValue];
 float floatAdd2Result=[add21.text floatValue]+[add22.text floatValue]+[add23.text floatValue];
 float floatAdd3Result=[add31.text floatValue]+[add32.text floatValue]+[add33.text floatValue];

 add1Result.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatAdd1Result];
 add2Result.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatAdd2Result];
 add3Result.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatAdd3Result];
}

-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
 [add11 resignFirstResponder];
 [add12 resignFirstResponder];
 [add13 resignFirstResponder];
 [add21 resignFirstResponder];
 [add22 resignFirstResponder];
 [add23 resignFirstResponder];
 [add31 resignFirstResponder];
 [add32 resignFirstResponder];
 [add33 resignFirstResponder];
}    

- (void)dealloc {
 [add11 release];
 [add12 release];
 [add13 release];
 [add21 release];
 [add22 release];
 [add23 release];
 [add31 release];
 [add32 release];
 [add33 release];
 [add1Result release];
 [add2Result release];
 [add2Result release];
 [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

My console says:

```
[Session started at 2011-01-24 18:33:13 -0600.]

WARNING: Falling back to active SDK directory at: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk

<snip>
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys004
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-3466-67
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
continue
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
<snip>
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
gdb stack trace around reply contains invalid hex digit:
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0018dc33 remote_backtrace_self + 54�
1   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0019081d fromhex + 65�
<snip>
43  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00085592 catch_errors + 78�
44  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008646b gdb_main + 63�
45  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00001f06 main + 52�
46  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00001e95 start + 53�
recent remote packet log at point of error:
Sent:  [1295915610.545:96] m3757d780,40
Recvd: [1295915610.548:96] 1800000074f9710fa01a33b5bb04c4aeabd6be7d220000803000000000000000000000000c3197080807000000e06c080000000064eaa708c8120000cc688b08
Sent:  [1295915610.548:96] m3757d7c0,40
Recvd: [1295915610.551:96] 

warning: Unable to read symbols from [memory object "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D" at 0x3076a000]: File format not recognized.
warning: Could not read dyld entry: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D from inferior memory at 0x3076a000 with slide 0x0 and length 4294967295.

The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).

[Session started at 2011-01-24 18:36:46 -0600.]
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
```

---

**Edit by Dave DeLong:**

I've trimmed down the code as much as I could. I've removed instance variable declarations and left the `@property` statements, collapsed `@synthesize` lines, simplified the code, stripped dead methods, snipped long repetitive stuff, etc.  I also removed the code download link, since it only linked to a zipped copy of the .xcodeproj file (but no source).

Comment: @user588343 StackOverflow is not a place where you can just dump a bunch of code and ask us to solve it for you. You need to show us that you tried to narrow it down to specific method(s) and show us what you've done to the effect of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're dying in the dynamic loader stuff would seem to imply that your binary didn't build correctly.  When I start getting strange errors, I find it's best to clean my entire project and re-build everything from scratch.  To clean, simply go to the Build menu and choose "Clean All Targets".  Once that finishes, try building and running again.

Comment: Sorry for dumping off all the code. I'm kinda new to developing. OK I tried cleaning my entire project and rebuilt it in the simulator again but it is still having the same problem. I tried making the code over again from scratch but still nothing. Im wonderning if you had a chance to look at my source file. Is there anything you could try to do to make it work. The link to my source file is above. Any help would be appreciated!!! I'm trying to make my first app for the app store. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user588343 the link you originally posted was only for an xcodeproj file, which just contains a list of the files in your project.  It doesn't actually contain the source.

Comment: What should I actually post? the whole application folder?? That is no problem if that is what you need

Comment: @user588343 the entire project folder (but please delete the "build" folder first) is necessary for compilation.  however, did you try cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: @DaveDeLong Sorry this is the updated one without the build foler. Here is the link: http://hotfile.com/dl/99515977/80ea468/SuperCalculator_copy_2.zip.html

Comment: Ya I did try cleaning and rebuilding but still no results:(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this helps to me:

1. restart your device
2. restart Xcode
3. clean all builds and clean xcode cache
4. delete all breakpoints... I have seen Xcode becoming crazy and normal again after deleting all breakpoints from a project. Sometimes Xcode loses its marbles and you have to help it.
5. as a radical measure right click on the xcodeproj file, choose Show Package Contents and delete everything inside that package except for the pbxproj file. Then reopen the project.

Before doing #5 make a backup of your project... just in case.

EDIT:

You may have a problem on your disk or Xcode. Use Disk Utility and verify/repair permissions on your disk, remove then reinstall Xcode / SDk from a fresh version. See if that works.

Comment: Just tried this... no results. I had the same results as I stated above. Gosh I don't know where I'm going wrong. It all looks right. could one of you maybe try to build this app with my source code or can you try making it again? its a window based application with a tab bar controller. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I have added an extra item to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. unplug the phone
2. delete the app from the phone (using the standard method of holding your finger on the icon until the ‘X’ appears)
3. Once deleted, plug back in and re-build
4. Again the app crashes on the device, but this time after the crash, unplug again and run it directly from the phone

Comment: I just tried this but still the same problem. The app opens up to a black screen with the status bar but it just gets stuck there.

Comment: you could try creating a new tab bar controller project and see if that clean project could run, then move your source code over in stages and compile to see if it runs, cheers.